# Can i host a website with a Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to know if i could do that.

I tried searching up on google but nothing came up.

I wanted to know if there was any spigot plugin that i could use.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hosting websites, which isn't about gaming and also a recommendation for mods.

Comment: what would the website even *do*? how would a website be a minecraft server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot host a website from a Minecraft server itself, but you can easily host a website at the same IP address and on the same server/machine as the Minecraft server using software like **Nginx** or **Apache**.